# Properly plotting an array in Xcode 7.3.1 Playgrounds

Tags: ios, plot, swift-playground

I am trying to examine what the distributions of various randomization functions look like in Xcode, so I made this playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

var distribution: [Int] = Array(count: 6, repeatedValue: 0)
for i in 1...100000 {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(6)
    distribution[Int(randomNumber)] += 1
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(distribution[Int(randomNumber)], withIdentifier: "Random Distribution")
}
```

What I was hoping to see was a line along the bottom of the chart, depicting a normal (or flat) distribution, but instead, I got this diagonal line. How do I get it to be level?

Comment: I was just fixing the strange artifacts that appeared in the code, when you beat me to it lol. thanks, @Eric

Answer (score 2):

You're capturing values as you're collecting them, you want final values instead:

```
for i in 0..<6 {
   XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(distribution[i], withIdentifier: "Distribution")
}
```

Comment: I believe it's the solution; but Xcode automatically expands the graph result vertically to occupy all the space, same for you? First it shows the flatish line then it expands the result on the Y axis. I don't know if we can force it otherwise.

Comment: @EricD that might make sense, except the array looks something like [1650, 1705, 1704, 1698, 1651, 1592], and so what I'm desiring, really, is just a graph with 6 values, (being that i'm looking at the distribution of choices between 6 numbers.) maybe if I did a range of 100 numbers through 10K iterations, I'd get more of a normal curve or flat curve depending on which random source I utilized, but anyway i'm not too sure the graph i'm looking at as a result has 6 points. it looks more like 10000...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fiddled around, and this works very nicely.

```
var distribution: [Int] = Array(count: 6, repeatedValue: 0)
let distributionSource = GKARC4RandomSource()
distributionSource.dropValuesWithCount(1024)
for i in 1...10000 {
    let randomNumber = distributionSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(6)
    distribution[Int(randomNumber)] += 1
}
for value in distribution  {
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(value, withIdentifier: "Random Distribution")
}
```

now I can alter the numbers and see my curves :-)

Comment: now all I need to know is what has replaced XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(value, withIdentifier:) after Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Nice, and fast! :) // I think that captureValue is deprecated because they favorite using the inline graphs. To do that, you just state the value to inspect in a loop and you click on the + sign on the right. [See my screenshot.](https://www.evernote.com/l/AFmM3poWESBESovQfM1PugbDMwCwdeyBAGI)

Comment: Oh @eric that's a huge improvement! I just wish that in every case of deprecation, Xcode would offer the new alternative.